# Scrapy appending Key: value pairs to another Key

Tags: python, mongodb, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrap the following a map coordinates , and I have the coordinates as var Data = {lat: 45.000000 , long : 68.00000}

I am able to scrap the above data items  'long':68.0000 and 'lat':45.0000 as separate items.

now How do I put them in to a new key 'loc'  as required by mongodb

loc:{long: 68.000000, 'lat':45.0000} ( I need long first and followed by lat values so that i can put  the scraped  data into mongodb ).

Hi all

This is my items file:

```
class Citylist(scrapy.Item):
    lng = scrapy.Field()
    lat = scrapy.Field()
    loc = scrapy.Filed()
```

This is my Spider file:

```
for newlist in HtmlXPathSelector(response).select('/html/body'):  
    l = ItemLoader(item=Citylist(),response = response)
    l.add_xpath('lng', '//......text()')
    l.add_xpath('lat', '//......text()')
    yield l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_output_value()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.ItemLoader.get_output_value) would give you the values of extracted `lng` and `lat`, [`add_value()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.ItemLoader.add_value) would put the value into the loader:

```
l.add_value('loc', {'lng': l.get_output_value('lng'), 
                    'lat': l.get_output_value('lat')})
```

Comment: Hi Alecxe, You rock!!! Thanks a lot It worked. But I still have a problem. I need lng and then lat. I think it is calling the values as per the alphabetic order. What can do to get lng before lat. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: @pjsuccess dictionaries are unordered collections, there is no guaranteed order.

Comment: So is there any hack for this. or how we can get around to bring them  in order. mongodb needs that order. pls advise

Comment: @pjsuccess are you sure mongodb needs the strict order here? Could you elaborate more and show how do you write items to mongodb? Thanks. (This could probably be a separate SO question)